# Files not being downloaded Properly. (Selenium)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to download from the list of links.

```
test_list = ['https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/RFQ/8/SPE1C122Q0058.PDF', 'https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/RFQ/8/SPE2DH22Q0028.PDF',
             'https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/RFQ/9/SPE2DH22Q0029.PDF', 'https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/RFQ/3/SPE2DS22Q0023.PDF',
             'https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/RFQ/1/SPE2DS22Q0031.PDF', 'https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/RFQ/3/SPE2DS22Q0033.PDF']
```

But this script is also downloading many copies of a single file. How to avoid this? I just want to download the six pdf files in the list.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
# # options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# options.headless = True
# prefs = {"download.default_directory": zip_dir,
#          "download.directory_upgrade": True,
#          "download.manager.showWhenStarting": False,
#          "download.manager.useWindow": False,
#          "helperApps.alwaysAsk.force":False,
#          "download.manager.showAlertOnComplete": False}
# options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)

dn = len(test_list)

for t in range(0,dn):
    URL = test_list[t]
    sleep(randint(3, 9))
    driver.get(URL)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id("butAgree").click()
    except:
        pass
```

Also tried with:

```
for t in test_list:
    URL = t
    sleep(randint(3, 9))
    driver.get(URL)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id("butAgree").click()
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do without Selenium, BeautifulSoup will suffice. The trick is to first retrieve validation keys from the base url `https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/dodwarning.aspx`, and subsequently download the files using these keys:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

test_list = ['https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/RFQ/8/SPE1C122Q0058.PDF', 'https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/RFQ/8/SPE2DH22Q0028.PDF',
             'https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/RFQ/9/SPE2DH22Q0029.PDF', 'https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/RFQ/3/SPE2DS22Q0023.PDF',
             'https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/RFQ/1/SPE2DS22Q0031.PDF', 'https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/Downloads/RFQ/3/SPE2DS22Q0033.PDF']

s = requests.Session()

def get_file(url):
    pagereq = s.get('https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/dodwarning.aspx')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pagereq.content, 'html.parser')

    viewstategenerator = soup.find("input", attrs = {'id': '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'})['value']
    viewstate = soup.find("input", attrs = {'id': '__VIEWSTATE'})['value']
    eventvalidation = soup.find("input", attrs = {'id': '__EVENTVALIDATION'})['value']

    headers = {
        'Origin': 'https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    }

    params = (
        ('goto', url.split('.mil', 1)[1]),
    )

    data = {
      '__VIEWSTATE': viewstate,
      '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': viewstategenerator,
      '__EVENTVALIDATION': eventvalidation,
      'butAgree': 'OK'
    }

    response = requests.post('https://dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil/dodwarning.aspx', headers=headers, params=params, data=data)

    with open(url.rsplit('/', 1)[1], 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
        
for i in test_list:
    get_file(i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: worked with six files, with many files , showed `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='dibbs2.bsm.dla.mil', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dodwarning.aspx?goto=%2FDownloads%2F
RFQ%2F0%2FSPE4A722Q0200.PDF (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002173433ED30>: Failed to establish a new connection:
 [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because
 connected host has failed to respond')) `

Comment: Set `time.sleep` to 2, 3 or higher. You're hitting the website's rate limit with so many requests.

Comment: what if I have to download 10000 files, it shows the error then

Comment: It all depends on the (unknown) rate limit. What if the website limits the number of downloads per IP address to 1,000 daily? You could create a try-except that continues downloading after a set time interval, or use proxies.